# How to add a PHP model as source to jQuery autocomplete source?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, postgresql

fellas.

I am in need of some help. I am trying to add a jQuery autocomplete to a PHP form. I have the autocomplete setup and with an array it works just fine. However, when I try to use a PHP model for a postgreSQL database it don't work.

The model itself is written with PHP and on the Yii1.1 framework. The "Tag.php" looks like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "tag".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'tag':
 * @property string $idtag
 * @property string $tag
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Dashboard[] $dashboards
 */
class Tag extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'tag';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('tag', 'required', 'message'=>'Please enter a tag'),
            array('tag', 'type', 'type'=>'string'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('idtag, tag', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /*
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'dashboards' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Dashboard', 'dashboard_has_tag(fk_idtag, fk_iddashboard)'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'idtag' => Yii::t('idtag', 'Tag ID'),
            'tag' => Yii::t('tag', 'Tag name'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('idtag',$this->idtag,true);
        $criteria->compare('LOWER(tag)',strtolower($this->tag),true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Tag the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

And the following code is how I am trying to actually set up the jQuery autocomplete:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
 
    // When selecting an item with the tab key, it wont move away from the text area.
    $("#tag_text").on("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON("Tag.php", {
            term: extractLast(request.term)}, response);
        },
        search: function() {
            // Custom min Length for the Tags to be searched.
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 2) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function() {
            // Prevents the insertion of a value as soon as one clicks it or selects it with the key.
            return false; 
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // Remove the current user input.
            terms.pop();
            // Add the selected item.
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // Add a placeholder to get comma and space at the end.
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
  </script>
```

As I said, if I use the source with a normal array it works just fine. However, I really need to get the data from a postgreSQL database. If anyone can help me with this, I would really appreciate.

EDIT:
I have been trying to get this to work but up until now it simply does not work. Not properly at least.
I simply can't bring my JS to work. The PHP part seems to work fine so far however, the JS does not display any data in the textarea field where the user input is going to be made.
Another thing is that I don't really get response data back. Below is the url that is calls the PHP function.

[image]

And here we see that I don't have any response data. However, I don't really know why that is the case.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a `CController` between, something like below.
I don't know yii1 but I tried my best:

```php
class TagController extends CController
{
    public function actionFind($term = null)
    {
        $tags = Tag::model()->findAll('tag LIKE :term', array(':term'=>$term));
        $data = array();
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $data[$tag->tagid] = $tag->tag;
        }
        return json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

In JS you call the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot @simialbi. I have an action in the Controller. Obviously I have not checked if I made any mistakes there. I will certainly give your function a go.

Comment: I have modified my controller to make it fit my needs better. However, now my JS function does not do it's job.
I think my call to the function seem to be bad. I use `$.getJson( <?php echo "'".Yii::app()->homeUrl.'?=path/to/action/Find'."'" ?>, {term: extractLast(request.term)}, response)`
However, my JS does not display the Autocomplete (I have two entries in the DB, one named Test and one named Blue). I simply can't see where I made a mistake.

Comment: What look the generated Code look like? What does the network tab in development tools of the browser say? Is the route correct?

Comment: The `$data` in the controller looks like the following when printing it with `print_r()`:
`Array(
[1] => Test
[2] => Blue
)`
The request URL returns a GET method with a code 200. The response returns the following when `console.log()`used: `ƒ (){return a.apply(b||this,c.concat(d.call(arguments)))}`

Comment: What looks the generated js code like? `console.log` of the result prints a function?

Comment: Not sure if I can follow correctly (or if I am loggin things wrong). However, in the `.autocomplete()` function, the `source: function(request, response)` returns a `term object` when `request` is logged, and the `response` returns aforementioned function.
`source: function(request, response) {
$.getJSON( <?php echo "'".Yii::app()->homeUrl.'?r=/dashboard/Find'."'" ?>, {
term: extractLast(request.term)}, response);
console.log(response);
},`
The result when logged will always be `ƒ (){return a.apply(b||this,c.concat(d.call(arguments)))}`

Comment: Could you paste the whole js code?

Comment: The JS code is up above in the question. This is the entire script I am using, if that is what you are looking for.
As for the response code, this is actually the entire value that is returned when logged.
And the source: `function(request, response)` and so on. Is the function I am using in the JS code that is written in the question.

Comment: Is there some you url you could share?

Comment: I edited the question. There you can see the URL that is called. It returns a Status 200 but I don't have any response data at all.